# How to split data into training/testing sets using sample function

Tags: r, split, sample

I've just started using R and I'm not sure how to incorporate my dataset with the following sample code:

```
sample(x, size, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
```

I have a dataset that I need to put into a training (75%) and testing (25%) set.
I'm not sure what information I'm supposed to put into the x and size?
Is x the dataset file, and size how many samples I have?

Comment: `x` can be the index (row/col nos. say) of your `data`. `size` can be `0.75*nrow(data)`. Try `sample(1:10, 4, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)` to see what it does.

Answer (score 316):

There are numerous approaches to achieve data partitioning. For a more complete approach take a look at the `createDataPartition` function in the `caret` package.

Here is a simple example:

```
data(mtcars)

## 75% of the sample size
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(mtcars))

## set the seed to make your partition reproducible
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), size = smp_size)

train <- mtcars[train_ind, ]
test <- mtcars[-train_ind, ]
```

Comment: I'm a little confused what guarantees this code returns a unique test and train df? It seems to work, don't get me wrong. Just having trouble understanding how subtracting the indices leads to unique observations. For instance, if you had a df with 10 rows and one column, and the one column contained 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and you followed this code, what prevents a train having index 4 and test having -6 -> 10 - 6 = 4 as well?

Comment: thank. I tried `mtcars[!train_ind]` and while it didn't fail, it did't work as expected. How could I subset using the `!`?

Comment: @user989762 `!` are used for logical (`TRUE/FALSE`) and not indices. If you want to subset using `!`, try something like mtcars[`!seq_len(nrow(mtcars)) %in% train_ind`, ] (not tested).

Comment: @VedaadShakib when you use "-" it omit all the index in train_ind from your data. Take a look at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html . Hope it helps

Comment: Indexing by `-train_ind` is doesn't do what he claims.  The minus does an elementwise negation of the numbers rather than selecting for those indices in `train` not picked by `train_ind`.  Not sure how this has 93 upvotes since train and test are not split sets of mtcars.  Wasted half hour on this and had to find a different solution.  Maybe it's a special legacy artifact that's since changed?

Comment: @EricLeschinski  Can you elaborate with some code or a gist on github ? there are probably other elegant way to do it. It is a 3 years old answer probably few things have changed but I don't really get what you are saying. Can you post it on a gist so that I will understand better why negative index doesn't work in this case ? If you have a better (universal) way, I would gladly edit my answer. Best

Comment: @ChristopherJohn Why it doesn't work can you explain with an example using a gist for example. I really want to understand to improve this answer from 2013. Thanks

Comment: @ChristopherJohn Thanks for your comment. I am indexing by numbers not row names, I don't understand why you want to use row names instead of integer to index a dataframe? (http://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2015/06/16/never-trust-the-row-names-of-a-dataframe-in-R/). For the point about the size of the data, I don't get why it will not work on large dataset, any reproductible example you can share with me, I fail to understand but I really want to improve this answer. Lastly, if you want me to remove the floor argument you will replace it by what ? (ceiling? round?). Cheers

Comment: I have deleted my comments, I cannot reproduce the problem I was having previously. Apologies. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopherJohn Thanks for the comment and I will look into ways to improve this answer, probably using the new modelr package (https://github.com/tidyverse/modelr).

Comment: What if we need a 5 fold or 10 fold validation? how do we make non overlapping test sets?

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: Isn't ```createDataPartition``` in ```caret``` and not ```caTools```?

Comment: Can someone explain me why do we set the seed? what does it do?

Comment: @coder_bg i am pretty sure it makes it so the sample being taken is consistent. Like if you just ran sample, it would pull different samples each time, but running set.seed keeps the sample consistent

Answer (score 119):

It can be easily done by:

```
set.seed(101) # Set Seed so that same sample can be reproduced in future also
# Now Selecting 75% of data as sample from total 'n' rows of the data  
sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(data), size = floor(.75*nrow(data)), replace = F)
train <- data[sample, ]
test  <- data[-sample, ]
```

By using [caTools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caTools/index.html) package:

```
require(caTools)
set.seed(101) 
sample = sample.split(data$anycolumn, SplitRatio = .75)
train = subset(data, sample == TRUE)
test  = subset(data, sample == FALSE)
```

Comment: I recently did a course with MIT and they used the approach using caTools throughout. Thanks

Comment: `sample = sample.split(data[,1], SplitRatio = .75)` Should remove the need to name a column.

Comment: https://github.com/cran/caTools/blob/master/R/sample.split.R
"Split data from vector Y into 2 bins in predefined ratio while preserving relative [ratios] of different labels in Y." So if this is for a classification problem, the first parameter should the column with the classes to be predicted. If it's a regression problem, might as well use the built-in sample function as in the former solution.

Answer (score 42):

I would use `dplyr` for this, makes it super simple. It does require an id variable in your data set, which is a good idea anyway, not only for creating sets but also for traceability during your project. Add it if doesn't contain already.

```
mtcars$id <- 1:nrow(mtcars)
train <- mtcars %>% dplyr::sample_frac(.75)
test  <- dplyr::anti_join(mtcars, train, by = 'id')
```

Answer (score 31):

This is almost the same code, but in more nice look

```
bound <- floor((nrow(df)/4)*3)         #define % of training and test set

df <- df[sample(nrow(df)), ]           #sample rows 
df.train <- df[1:bound, ]              #get training set
df.test <- df[(bound+1):nrow(df), ]    #get test set
```

Comment: Yup! Nice look!

Comment: does this randomly pick data? is the `sample` method provided built in ?

Comment: Yes, it does at the step `df <- df[sample(nrow(df)), ]` where all the rows are randomly sampled. Take a look at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sample for more information of `sample` function which is the R base function.

Answer (score 24):

```
library(caret)
intrain<-createDataPartition(y=sub_train$classe,p=0.7,list=FALSE)
training<-m_train[intrain,]
testing<-m_train[-intrain,]
```

Comment: While a code-only answer is an answer, it is better to provide some explanation.

Comment: what is m_train? I think you meant, sub_train the original data.frame. Therefore, the revised code should be training<-sub_train[intrain,] and testing<-sub_train[-intrain,]. I wonder why nobody was able to spot this major problem with you answer in the past five years!

Comment: OP didn't explicitly asked for stratification...

Answer (score 22):

I will split 'a' into train(70%) and test(30%)

```
    a # original data frame
    library(dplyr)
    train<-sample_frac(a, 0.7)
    sid<-as.numeric(rownames(train)) # because rownames() returns character
    test<-a[-sid,]
```

done

Comment: you need to import dpyr package, require(dplyr)

Comment: This answer helped me but I did need to tweak it to get expected results. As is, the dataset 'train' has rownames = sid of sequential integers: 1,2,3,4,... whereas you want sid to be the rownumbers from the original dataset 'a,' which since they are randomly selected won't be the sequential integers. So, it's necessary to create the id variable on 'a' first.

Comment: row.names(mtcars) <- NULL; train<-dplyr::sample_frac(mtcars, 0.5); test<-mtcars[-as.numeric(row.names(train)),] # I did this to my data, the original code doesn't work if your row names are set to numbers already

Comment: it looks ok for me, but do not seems to be random selection

Answer (score 17):

My solution is basically the same as dickoa's but a little easier to interpret:

```
data(mtcars)
n = nrow(mtcars)
trainIndex = sample(1:n, size = round(0.7*n), replace=FALSE)
train = mtcars[trainIndex ,]
test = mtcars[-trainIndex ,]
```

Comment: What is the variable swiss?

Answer (score 16):

I can suggest using the rsample package:

```
# choosing 75% of the data to be the training data
data_split <- initial_split(data, prop = .75)
# extracting training data and test data as two seperate dataframes
data_train <- training(data_split)
data_test  <- testing(data_split)
```

Comment: It is worth highlighting that `rsample` is part of the `tidymodels` framework for those using tidymodels. In addition to `initial_split` there is also `group_initial_split` and `initial_time_split`.

Answer (score 10):

After looking through all the different methods posted here, I didn't see anyone utilize `TRUE/FALSE` to select and unselect data. So I thought I would share a method utilizing that technique.

```
n = nrow(dataset)
split = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.75, 0.25))

training = dataset[split, ]
testing = dataset[!split, ]
```

## Explanation

There are multiple ways of selecting data from R, most commonly people use positive/negative indices to select/unselect respectively. However, the same functionalities can be achieved by using `TRUE/FALSE` to select/unselect.

Consider the following example.

```
# let's explore ways to select every other element
data = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)


# using positive indices to select wanted elements
data[c(1, 3, 5)]
[1] 1 3 5

# using negative indices to remove unwanted elements
data[c(-2, -4)]
[1] 1 3 5

# using booleans to select wanted elements
data[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]
[1] 1 3 5

# R recycles the TRUE/FALSE vector if it is not the correct dimension
data[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
[1] 1 3 5
```

Comment: I find this to be the most elegant native R solution with no external packages.

Answer (score 7):

Just a more brief and simple way using awesome **dplyr** library:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(275) #to get repeatable data

data.train <- sample_frac(Default, 0.7)

train_index <- as.numeric(rownames(data.train))
data.test <- Default[-train_index, ]
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `Default[-train_index,]` for the last line.

Answer (score 6):

`scorecard` package has a useful function for that, where you can specify the ratio and seed

```
library(scorecard)

dt_list <- split_df(mtcars, ratio = 0.75, seed = 66)
```

The test and train data are stored in a list and can be accessed by calling `dt_list$train` and `dt_list$test`

Answer (score 5):

If you type:

```
?sample
```

If will launch a help menu to explain what the parameters of the sample function mean.

I am not an expert, but here is some code I have:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(400), nrow=100))
splitdata <- split(data[1:nrow(data),],sample(rep(1:4,as.integer(nrow(data)/4))))
test <- splitdata[[1]]
train <- rbind(splitdata[[1]],splitdata[[2]],splitdata[[3]])
```

This will give you 75% train and 25% test.

Answer (score 4):

My solution shuffles the rows, then takes the first 75% of the rows as train and the last 25% as test. Super simples!

```
row_count <- nrow(orders_pivotted)
shuffled_rows <- sample(row_count)
train <- orders_pivotted[head(shuffled_rows,floor(row_count*0.75)),]
test <- orders_pivotted[tail(shuffled_rows,floor(row_count*0.25)),]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can divide data into a particular ratio here it is 80% train and 20% in a test dataset.

```
ind <- sample(2, nrow(dataName), replace = T, prob = c(0.8,0.2))
train <- dataName[ind==1, ]
test <- dataName[ind==2, ]
```

Comment: Be careful as this is based on probability, so using this will not always create an exact 80-20% split.  Easiest is just to use `createDataPartition` from the `caret` package as mentioned above. For instance, after just running it 3 times consecutively I got 45 train samples and just 5 test out of 50 (90-10).

Answer (score 2):

Below a function that create a **`list` of sub-samples of the same size** which is not exactly what you wanted but might prove usefull for others. In my case to create multiple classification trees on smaller samples to test overfitting :

```
df_split <- function (df, number){
  sizedf      <- length(df[,1])
  bound       <- sizedf/number
  list        <- list() 
  for (i in 1:number){
    list[i] <- list(df[((i*bound+1)-bound):(i*bound),])
  }
  return(list)
}
```

Example :

```
x <- matrix(c(1:10), ncol=1)
x
# [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    2
# [3,]    3
# [4,]    4
# [5,]    5
# [6,]    6
# [7,]    7
# [8,]    8
# [9,]    9
#[10,]   10

x.split <- df_split(x,5)
x.split
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2

# [[2]]
# [1] 3 4

# [[3]]
# [1] 5 6

# [[4]]
# [1] 7 8

# [[5]]
# [1] 9 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Use caTools package in R 
sample code will be as follows:-

```
data
split = sample.split(data$DependentcoloumnName, SplitRatio = 0.6)
training_set = subset(data, split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(data, split == FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use base R. Function `runif` generates uniformly distributed values from 0 to 1.By varying cutoff value (train.size in example below), you will always have approximately the same percentage of random records below the cutoff value.

```
data(mtcars)
set.seed(123)

#desired proportion of records in training set
train.size<-.7
#true/false vector of values above/below the cutoff above
train.ind<-runif(nrow(mtcars))<train.size

#train
train.df<-mtcars[train.ind,]


#test
test.df<-mtcars[!train.ind,]
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it showed the extra couple lines to actually create the training and test sets (which newbies often struggle with).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming **df** is your data frame, and that you want to create **75% train** and **25% test**

```
all <- 1:nrow(df)
train_i <- sort(sample(all, round(nrow(df)*0.75,digits = 0),replace=FALSE))
test_i <- all[-train_i]
```

Then to create a train and test data frames

```
df_train <- df[train_i,]
df_test <- df[test_i,]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require(caTools)

set.seed(101)            #This is used to create same samples everytime

split1=sample.split(data$anycol,SplitRatio=2/3)

train=subset(data,split1==TRUE)

test=subset(data,split1==FALSE)
```

The `sample.split()` function will add one extra column 'split1' to dataframe and 2/3 of the rows will have this value as TRUE and others as FALSE.Now the rows where split1 is TRUE will be copied into train and other rows will be copied to test dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of `sample` for splitting if you look for reproducible results. If your data changes even slightly, the split will vary even if you use `set.seed`. For example, imagine the sorted list of IDs in you data is all the numbers between 1 and 10. If you just dropped one observation, say 4, sampling by location would yield a different results because now 5 to 10 all moved places.

An alternative method is to use a hash function to map IDs into some pseudo random numbers and then sample on the mod of these numbers. This sample is more stable because assignment is now determined by the hash of each observation, and not by its relative position.

For example:

```
require(openssl)  # for md5
require(data.table)  # for the demo data

set.seed(1)  # this won't help `sample`

population <- as.character(1e5:(1e6-1))  # some made up ID names

N <- 1e4  # sample size

sample1 <- data.table(id = sort(sample(population, N)))  # randomly sample N ids
sample2 <- sample1[-sample(N, 1)]  # randomly drop one observation from sample1

# samples are all but identical
sample1
sample2
nrow(merge(sample1, sample2))
```

[1] 9999

```
# row splitting yields very different test sets, even though we've set the seed
test <- sample(N-1, N/2, replace = F)

test1 <- sample1[test, .(id)]
test2 <- sample2[test, .(id)]
nrow(test1)
```

[1] 5000

```
nrow(merge(test1, test2))
```

[1] 2653

```
# to fix that, we can use some hash function to sample on the last digit

md5_bit_mod <- function(x, m = 2L) {
  # Inputs: 
  #  x: a character vector of ids
  #  m: the modulo divisor (modify for split proportions other than 50:50)
  # Output: remainders from dividing the first digit of the md5 hash of x by m
  as.integer(as.hexmode(substr(openssl::md5(x), 1, 1)) %% m)
}

# hash splitting preserves the similarity, because the assignment of test/train 
# is determined by the hash of each obs., and not by its relative location in the data
# which may change 
test1a <- sample1[md5_bit_mod(id) == 0L, .(id)]
test2a <- sample2[md5_bit_mod(id) == 0L, .(id)]
nrow(merge(test1a, test2a))
```

[1] 5057

```
nrow(test1a)
```

[1] 5057

sample size is not exactly 5000 because assignment is probabilistic, but it shouldn't be a problem in large samples thanks to the law of large numbers.

See also: http://blog.richardweiss.org/2016/12/25/hash-splits.html
and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20742/statistical-properties-of-hash-functions-when-calculating-modulo

Comment: Added as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769681/reproducible-splitting-of-data-into-training-and-testing-in-r

Comment: I want to develop auto.arima model from multiple time series data and I want to use 1 year of data, 3 year of data, 5, 7... in a two year interval from each series to build the model and testing it in the remaining testing set. How do I do the subsetting so that the fitted model will have what I want? I appreciate for your help

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this one, it can help too.

```
set.seed(12)
data = Sonar[sample(nrow(Sonar)),]#reshufles the data
bound = floor(0.7 * nrow(data))
df_train = data[1:bound,]
df_test = data[(bound+1):nrow(data),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an index row "rowid" and use anti join to filter out using by = "rowid". You can remove the rowid column by using %>% select(-rowid) after the split.

> data <- tibble::rowid_to_column(data)
>
> set.seed(11081995)
>
> testdata <- data %>% slice_sample(prop = 0.2)
>
> traindata <- anti_join(data, testdata, by = "rowid")

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(123)
llwork<-sample(1:length(mydata),round(0.75*length(mydata),digits=0)) 
wmydata<-mydata[llwork, ]
tmydata<-mydata[-llwork, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve the problem:

```
df = data.frame(read.csv("data.csv"))
# Split the dataset into 80-20
numberOfRows = nrow(df)
bound = as.integer(numberOfRows *0.8)
train=df[1:bound ,2]
test1= df[(bound+1):numberOfRows ,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `dplyr` to `mutate` the values

```
set.seed(1)
mutate(x, train = runif(1) < 0.75)
```

I can keep using `dplyr::filter` with helper functions like

```
data.split <- function(is_train = TRUE) {
    set.seed(1)
    mutate(x, train = runif(1) < 0.75) %>%
    filter(train == is_train)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function (my first one, so it might not work well) to make this go faster if I'm working with multiple data tables and don't want to repeat the code.

```
xtrain <- function(data, proportion, t1, t2){
  data <- data %>% rowid_to_column("rowid")
  train <- slice_sample(data, prop = proportion)
  assign(t1, train, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  test <- data %>% anti_join(as.data.frame(train), by = "rowid")
  assign(t2, test, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

xtrain(iris, .80, 'train_set', 'test_set')
```

You'll need to have dplyr and tibble loaded. This takes a given dataset, the proportion you want use for sampling, and two object names. The function creates the table and then assigns them as an object in your global environment.

Answer (score 0):

try using `idx <- sample(2, nrow(data), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.75, 0.25))` and the using the provided ids to access split data `training <- data[idx == 1,] testing <- data[idx == 2,]`

Answer (score -2):

There is a very simple way to select a number of rows using the R index for rows and columns. This lets you CLEANLY split the data set given a number of rows - say the 1st 80% of your data.

In R all rows and columns are indexed so DataSetName[1,1] is the value assigned to the first column and first row of "DataSetName". I can select rows using [x,] and columns using [,x]

For example: If I have a data set conveniently named "data" with 100 rows I can view the first 80 rows using

> View(data[1:80,])

In the same way I can select these rows and subset them using:

> train = data[1:80,]
>
> test = data[81:100,]

Now I have my data split into two parts without the possibility of resampling. Quick and easy.

Comment: Althought it is true that data can be split that way, it is not advised. Some datasets are ordered by a variable that you are not aware of. So its best to sample which rows will be considered as training instead of taking the first n rows.

Comment: If you shuffle the data before separating them to test and training set, your suggestion works.