# Create data partition into training, testing and validation - split in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret

I wanted to split my training data in to 70% training, 15% testing and 15% validation. I am using the `createDataPartition()` function of the caret package. I am splitting it like the following

```
train <- read.csv("Train.csv")
test <- read.csv("Test.csv")

split=0.70
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(train$age, p=split, list=FALSE)
data_train <- train[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- train[-trainIndex,]
```

Is there any way of splitting into training, testing and validation using `createDataPartition()` like the following `H2o` approach?

```
data.hex <- h2o.importFile("Train.csv")
splits <- h2o.splitFrame(data.hex, c(0.7,0.15), destination_frames = c("train","valid","test"))
train.hex <- splits[[1]]
valid.hex <- splits[[2]]
test.hex  <- splits[[3]]
```

Comment: Do two splits: (1) original data into training and temp and (2) temp into testing and validation.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068963/r-how-to-split-a-data-frame-into-training-validation-and-test-sets

Comment: August 2017: there's now the `rsample` package in R https://topepo.github.io/rsample/

Answer (score 9):

A method using the `sample()` function in base R is

```
splitSample <- sample(1:3, size=nrow(data.hex), prob=c(0.7,0.15,0.15), replace = TRUE)
train.hex <- data.hex[splitSample==1,]
valid.hex <- data.hex[splitSample==2,]
test.hex <- data.hex[splitSample==3,]
```

Comment: `> nrow(data.hex)
[1] 25192
> nrow(train.hex)
[1] 8398
> valid.hex <- data.hex[splitSample==2,]
> nrow(valid.hex)
[1] 8397
> test.hex<- data.hex[splitSample==3,]
> nrow(test.hex)
[1] 8397` but the difference between them is only 1. is this correct?

Comment: Oops. Forgot the size argument.

Comment: Note that this is (quasi) random, so the sizes will be approximately equal to 0.7, 0.15, 0.15, but not exactly. For replication purposes, you would want to set the seed above the first line: `set.seed(some integer)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [train,validation, test split model in CARET in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256553/train-validation-test-split-model-in-caret-in-r). The idea is to use createDataPartition() twice. First time p=0.7 to create 70% train and 30% remaining data. Second time p=0.5 on remaining data to create 15% testing and 15% validate.