# Splitting a matrix into test and train set

Tags: r, matrix, training-data

I have a matrix with 10 rows and 4 columns. I want to use the first 5 rows as a training data set . I want to know if in R we can do that or do I need to turn a matrix into a Vector?

Comment: Use `training <- m1[1:5,]` or `training <- head(m1, 5)`

Comment: Or for 3+ sets [R: How to split a data frame into training, validation, and test sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36068963/8366499)