# How to find the range of kmeans clusters?

Tags: r, k-means

if I have this

```
   x = c(0.5,0.1,0.3,6,5,2,1,4,2,1,0.9,3,6,99,22,11,44,55)
```

apply kmeans

```
   kmeans(x, centers=5, iter.max = 10, nstart = 1)
```

this gives:

```
        Cluster means:
          [,1]
    1 99.00
    2 49.50
    3  22.00
    4  7.00
    5  1.48

     Clustering vector:
      [1] 5 5 5 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 1 3 4 2 2
```

Now I want to classify my values in x2 based on the clusters of x (1,2,3,4,5). How to do this?

```
x2 = c(0.3,1,3,0.66,0.5,0.2,0.1,64,92,21,0.93,93,6,99,22,11,44,55)
```

Comment: k-means isn't really designed for prediction on new data. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49017208/89482).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a naive approch based on distance to centroids of each cluster:

```
km <-  kmeans(x, centers=5, iter.max = 10, nstart = 1)
group <- sapply(x2, function(xx) which.min(abs(km$centers - xx)))

plot(x = x, y = rep(1, length(x)), col = km$cluster)
points(x = km$centers, y = rep(1, length(km$centers)), col = "purple", pch = "*")
points(x = x2, y = rep(1, length(x2)), col = group, pch = "+")
```

Please check the link provided by @neilfws about doing predictions with `kmeans`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Just one question. When I do > km$centers
   [,1]
1  1.48
2 49.50
3  7.00
4 99.00
5 22.00.......... so cluster 5    is  22. but when I do km$cluster, cluster 5 is 1.48. I am confused.

Comment: See `?kmeans`: 'A vector of integers (from 1:k) indicating the cluster to which each point is allocated', here from your object `x` each integer is the corresponding cluster

Answer (score 1):

There is a predict method for kmeans clusters in the `fdm2id` package. Load the package and type `?KMEANS` and `?predict.kmeans` for more information.

```
library(data.table)
library(fdm2id)
#
x  <- c(0.5,0.1,0.3,6,5,2,1,4,2,1,0.9,3,6,99,22,11,44,55)
dt <- data.table(x2 = c(0.3,1,3,0.66,0.5,0.2,0.1,64,92,21,0.93,93,6,99,22,11,44,55))
dt[, pred:=predict(KMEANS(x, k = 5), newdata=x2)]
```

Note that the cluster numbers are arbitrary in the sense that they merely distinguish between clusters, so the numbering might not be the same but the cluster membership should align.