# Partition data to train and test in R

Tags: r

I am trying to partition my data set(my.data2) to train and test, but when I run the below script, I got an error show below:

```
ind<-sample(2,nrow(my.data2),replace = TRUE, prob=c(0.8,0.2))
train <- my.data2[ind=1, ]
test <- my.data2[ind=2,]
```

I will get the following error:

```
Error in `[.tbl_df`(my.data2, ind = 1, ) : unused argument (ind = 1)
```

Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use`==` instead of `=`.

I would also suggest to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17200430/5184851). It will give you a nice idea how you can split data into a train-to-test ratio.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works, I am a rookie level beginner of r, appreciate the help!