# how to divide dataset to test and train whit respect of a group

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to divide my data set into train and test data. but I have one column as a group.All  member of a group must be in train or test. for example if the group column is like this:

```
         group
           1
           1
           1
           1
           1
           2
           2
           2
           3
           3
```

if one of the row of first group is in train set the first 5 rows must be in there and ...

Comment: Instead of sample on rows, sample on unique group ids instead.

Comment: What is your algorithm for train/test split? How are you currently splitting now?

Comment: Start with `by(x, x$group, ...)`, then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278115/3358272 (second recommendation) for what to do in that `...`-placeholder.

Comment: @r2evans could you plz make an answer? I am not sure

Comment: How do you decide which groups will go into test set and which will go into train?

Comment: randomly , I know the number of groups that should be in train

Comment: How many should be in train?

Comment: roughly about 11000 groups in train and 5000 in test

Comment: Use Phil's answer, do `train.groups <- sample(unique(dat$group), 11000)` and then get `dat.train` and `dat.test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`. `dat_train` and `dat_test` is the final result. I assume a case with 10000 group of training dataset and `5000` group of testing dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(12345)

# Create an example data frame with group and data
dat <- tibble(group = rep(1:15000, each = 5),
              data = rnorm(75000))

# Step 1: Create a look up table showing group number
g <- dat %>% distinct(group)

# Step 2: Use sample_n to sampel for train
g_train <- g %>% sample_n(size = 10000)

# Step 3: Use semi_join and anti_join to split dat into train and test
dat_train <- dat %>% semi_join(g_train, by = "group")
dat_test <- dat %>% anti_join(g_train, by = "group")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a total of 20 groups and you want 8 groups in the training set and the remaining 12 in your test set.

First, let's generate some data to play with:

```
dat <- data.frame(group=factor(rep(1:20, each=5)), value=rnorm(100))
```

As you want to sample by group rather than observation, now draw a random sample of size 8 from groups for your training set and put the rest into the test set.

```
train.groups <- sample(levels(dat$group), 8)
dat.train <- dat[dat$group %in% train.groups, ]
dat.test <- dat[!(dat$group %in% train.groups), ]
```

Comment: what is each=5?

Comment: From ?rep:

    ‘each’ non-negative integer.  Each element of ‘x’ is repeated ‘each’ times.  Other inputs will be coerced to an integer or double vector and the first element taken.  Treated as ‘1’ if ‘NA’ or invalid.

Comment: I mean why 5?  rep is repeating 20 groups 5 times? why?

Comment: Well, to replicate your example, where you also had 5 instances of at least the first group. But it does not really matter for the solution.

Comment: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid first argument

Comment: `sample` ≠ `sample.int`. They take different parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `dplyr` and `tidyverse` (package) to solve this.

Assuming your dataset's name is `df1`.

Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

training_data <- df1 %>% filter(group=1)

testing_data <- df1 %>% filter(group=2)
```

Comment: what is group 1 and 2?

Comment: `filter(group=1)` will fail, perhaps you mean `filter(group == 1)`? (Please test your code with some data before posting.)