# Split a data set into a training and test set with runif

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

I have a question regarding a command. We used in a class runif to create a training set, that should contain 50% of the data set. (we developed a decision tree based on this training set). But I still can't understand the logic behind this command, could someone explain to me how this works?

I understand the decision trees, and the logic behind splitting up a data set, my question is just explicitly about how this command works.

```
inTrain <- runif(nrow(USArrests)) < 0.5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split data into training/testing sets using sample function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200114/how-to-split-data-into-training-testing-sets-using-sample-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dataset named `USArrests` with length `nrow(USArrests)`, let's say for the sake of simplification 100. So `runif(nrow(USArrests))` creates 100 uniform distributed random numbers i.e. for every row in your dataset one number.

Next your expression `runif(nrow(USArrests)) < 0.5` checks, if the number is `< 0.5` or not returning `TRUE` or `FALSE`. This gives you a logical vector of length 100 (or `nrow(USArrests)`) that indicates, if a row belongs to the training or to the test dataset.

It's not shown but finally you select your training data by

```
USArrests[inTrain,]
```

and your test data by

```
USArrests[-inTrain,]
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot.