# 0 observations of N variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset, which looks like:

```
y  Age   Height
0  Aage  Aheight
1  Bage  Bheight
```

All variables are divided into at least two categories.
When I open dataset with the code:

```
DM_input = read.csv(file="C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.CSV",header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

R correctly shows: 5040 observations of 11 variables.
When I try to break down dataset into test and train with the following code:

```
> train <- DM_input[DM_input$rand <= 0.7, c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)]
> test <- DM_input[DM_input$rand > 0.7, c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)]
```

I get 0 observations out of 11 variables, and the tables are empty.
I do not understand why that is happening, I removed special characters - it did not help.
Thanks

Comment: Could you use `dput(DM_input[1:10,])` to show us the first few rows of your data?  If we can't see what's in `DM_input`, we aren't going to be able to help you.

Comment: What does `range(DM_input$rand)` return? Also `c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` can be written as `2:10`.

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: @user2554330 this query returns perfectly all the data with proper reading each var as factor

Comment: The warning message you are seeing means that `DM_input$rand` is length 0.  Are you sure you have a column with that exact name?  Remember that R is case-sensitive, so `DM_input$Rand` would be different.

Answer (score 0):

I think that sample.int could help you to break down dataset.

Here is a example:

```
data(iris)

# number of rows of dataset
size_iris <- nrow(iris)

# set the proportion of sample split to 0.7
size_sample <- floor(0.7*size_iris)

# set a reproducible random result
set.seed(2020)

# sample the dataset
mysample <- sample.int(n=size_iris, size=size_sample, replace=F)
train <- iris[mysample,]
test <- iris[-mysample,]

# checking sizes
size_iris
[1] 150
nrow(train)
[1] 105
nrow(test)
[1] 45
```

There is a similar question here with a lot of good answers: [How to split data into training/testing sets using sample function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17200114/1675856)