# Getting Error in terms..formula: '.' in formula and no data argument in using train() function in lm

Tags: r, lm, training-data

New to this community and thanks in advance for any help.  I am just getting
started in using R for modeling and have run across the above error.  This is for
a simple formula using `mtcars` R dataset. Can anyone provide some suggestions to fix it?
I ran across similar questions in the archives but couldn't find a solution.

```r
LMfit1 <-train(mtcars$mpg ~ ., data =TrainData, method = "lm")
    
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
 '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `LMfit1 <- lm(mtcars$mpg ~ ., data = TrainData)`

Also, make sure you have TrainData defined somewhere.

If you can't get that to work, either use

```
lm(mtcars$mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
```

or create a TrainData ([here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200114/how-to-split-data-into-training-testing-sets-using-sample-function))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding.
1.This didn't work.
LMfit1<- lm(mtcars$mpg ~ ., data= TrainData)

2. This did work.
   LMfit1<- lm(mtcars$mpg ~., data=mtcars)
3. I think the problem is in the TrainData set.  I know that the TrainData is numeric; I tried converting to data.frame   (as.data.frame) but didn't help.  Here is the build:

DataSplit <- createDataPartition(y = car_dat$mpg, p=0.7, list= FALSE)

TrainData <- car_dat[DataSplit]

TestData <- car_dat[-DataSplit]