# Fitting classification trees and use the test set

Tags: r, tree, classification, sample

```
library(tree)
library(ISLR)
data("Carseats")
High<-ifelse(Carseats$Sales<=8,'No','Yes')
Carseats<-data.frame(Carseats,High)
tree.Carseats<-tree(as.factor(High)~.-Sales, data = Carseats)
summary(tree.Carseats)
plot(tree.Carseats)
text(tree.Carseats,pretty=0)
set.seed(1)
train=sample(1:nrow(Carseats),200)
```

I am writing to ask about the code `train=sample(1:nrow(Carseats),200)`.

The result of this code simply show the data and I cannot use `View(train)` to see the data set.

IMO,I think for the `sample`, we are going to choose the row of the dataset `data(Carseats)`, each element should contain some labels such as Sales, Income...

Maybe I am confused with the theoretical ideas behind.

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200114/how-to-split-data-into-training-testing-sets-using-sample-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `train=...` line of code is just creating an integer vector of 200 random numbers (between 1 and `nrow(Carseats)`). You need to actually subset the data. Something like this:

```
train_index <- sample(nrow(Carseats), 200)
training_data <- Carseats[train_index, ]
```

Then you'll want your test data to have the remaining observations, e.g.,

```
test_data <- Carseats[-train_index, ]
```

Comment: thank you very much @heds1 I make prefect sense

Comment: can I ask what does the comma ```,```  mean in ```[]```? what should I type for help in R. maybe ```?[]```?

Comment: You can type `?\`[\`` for the help for that, it's data-frame subsetting syntax. I think it would be a good idea to take a beginner R course or work through some of the basics -- it will be hard to do statistical modelling without that foundation :)

Comment: I am currently self-studying the book An introduction to statistical learning with application in R :p. If you would recommend some resources for self studying, that would be great @heds1 <3

Comment: BTW, the book shows ```Carseats.test<-Carseats[-train,]``` and ```High.test=HIgh[-train]``` why one has ```,```, one doesn't